# How to change console caret size?

Tags: vb.net

I have console application in and I need to change the caret size. But it isn't working.
I'm using the functions from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Here is my code:

```
Module MyApplication
    ' Functions
    Private Declare Function CreateCaret Lib "user32.dll" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal hBitmap As Integer, _
         ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer) As Boolean

    Private Declare Function ShowCaret Lib "user32.dll" _
        (ByVal hWnd As Integer) As Boolean

    Private Declare Function SetCaretPos Lib "user32.dll" _
        (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As Boolean

    Sub Main()
        CreateCaret(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, 0, 20, 8)
        SetCaretPos(0, 0)
        ShowCaret(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub 
End Module
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong functions.  A console is not a normal window, and can't be treated as one.

You need to use the console-specific functions, such as [SetConsoleCursorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

You can find information about the console, the functions and types available for working with it, and examples (mostly in C and C++) for using those functions and types at the MSDN site under [Consoles (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)